# Is it safe to store an old hard drive on top of a stack of VHS tapes? Will it damage the tapes?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, vhs

I set an old HDD on a stack of VHS tapes. Is this likely to have damaged the tapes?

The drive has been on them for about three days. I don't currently have a VHS player, so I can't check.

Comment: HDD's *do* have powerful magnets. That said, likely the VHS tape have already degraded through age, and the slight magnetic field leaking from the drive is unlikely to make a noticeable change.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik so it's a good idea to separate them, but the tapes are probably fine, or at least not much worse than before?

Comment: Hard drives have powerful magnets, but they are so heavily shielded they pose no risks to magnetic tapes like VHS tapes. I would not worry about this at all.

Answer (score 2):

Spinning disk hard drives do indeed have powerful magnets. If you hold a piece lightweight steel near any hard drive enclosure, you'll find that the magnetism does not escape the case.

There is going to be no "escaping" magnetism that will affect the video tapes.

Your question could have been interpreted as asking if one could store the data of a hard drive on video tape. This was available during the latter part of the last century and was notoriously unreliable. Source: direct experience.

Comment: I fixed the wording so it is clear that the hard drive is physically stored on top of the VHS tapes. Not a case where the VHS tapes might be seen as a way of storing data.

Comment: I wasn't criticizing so much as making an observation. I liked the original phrasing.

Answer (score -1):

The magnetic field would need to be grossly stronger to make any difference for the tapes.
The greater danger is; the HDD slipping off the tape-tops and breaking due to the impact.

**Ref:**
*Practical test; Using a 2"/5cm diameter loudspeaker magnet on a 3.5" diskette; no harm done regardless of how much you rub it against the diskette cover. Note that his magnet comes very much closer to the media than in the example above, AND it is a stronger magnet.*

**Guessing:** *An AC voltage (note: dynamic field!) driven electromagnet might be a larger demagnetization danger).*